# Break RSA given $N, e$ and lower half of $d$

Tags: rsa

I have full bits of public key $(n,e=65537)$ but from the private key, I have the lower half bits of $d$.

Can I restore the whole RSA private key from that data and use it for decryption?

Comment: If it's just several bits, you could easily brute force it.

Comment: You could also use [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2008/510) or its references / prior work if you have ~27% or more of the bits of $d$.

Comment: To test you can of course simply decrypt. If the insecure plain RSA is used you could still perform a sign / verify (over any data, including the empty string) to test the correctness of the key pair.

Comment: Which bits of $d$ do you have?  You can make a plausible guess of almost half of the upper bits of $d$ from $n, e$ (assuming small $e$), and so knowing those bits wouldn't help.  Knowing the lower bits of $d$, on the other hand, would be of great help...

Comment: @poncho I have the lower half of D part. Also, I have an encrypted message, that I should decrypt. E part is 65537

Comment: @poncho, How to obtain upper bits of d easily from n, e? Can you please point to the algorithm?

Comment: @satya: it's quite simple, we have $e \cdot d = 1 + k (p-1)(q-1) / \text{gcd}(p-1, q-1)$ for some integer $k$.  Now, $k < e$ (assuming they use the minimal value for $d$), $\text{gcd}(p-1, q-1)$ is probably small, and $n \approx (p-1)(q-1)$ (agree in the top half of the bits assuming $p$ and $q$ are the same size), and so we have $d \approx r \cdot n$ for some simple rational number $r$; guess various likely values of $r$, and one is likely to be correct...

Comment: @poncho Thank you for the explanation poncho. That makes sense. Is there a name for the technique? I just would like see the detailed analysis of it.

Comment: @satya: I have no idea about a name; it just occurred to me.  However, it would appear to be likely that someone else thought of it first; I just wouldn't know who that would be.

Comment: @satya Thanks for your answer. But how lower half bits of d can help me in that technique?

Comment: May be helpful. https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F3-540-49649-1_3.pdf

Answer (score 2):

If $e$ is small, and if you have $n/4$ least significant bits of $d$, then you can factorize $N$. The attack runs in time polynomial in $e, n$. You can have a look at [Boneh Durfee Frankel attack](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F3-540-49649-1_3.pdf) Section 3. So, if $e$ is only 65537, then the attack is certainly feasible.